# plt.hist Max bin index is different from the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to get the gray value with maximum pixels count in an image. I am using `plt.hist`

```
b, bins, patches = plt.hist(vals, 255)
plt.xlim([0,255])
```

After plotting the histogram, the result is 
[image]

The problem is the max index I am getting from `np.argmax(b)` is different from the visual maximum in the plot!
Why? For example, this histogram plot shows that the gray level with maximum pixels is definitely higher than 150 but `argmax` says it is at 142.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `255` is interprteted as the number of bins only, doesn't specify where these bins fall, this is done automatically by matplotlib.  So if your lowest value is 100 and the largest is 200, you will have 255 bins "crammed up" within [100, 200]. Try `plt.hist(vals, bins=np.arange(255))` instead. This way each bin index will correspond to actual value. Other option is to use `bins[np.argmax(b)]` to get the most common value.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you. 
Is this information mentioned in the documentation?.

Comment: Well check the documentation yourself?

Comment: Yes I checked it 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html 
But couldn't find this "crammed up" effect.

Comment: "If an integer is given, bins + 1 bin edges are calculated and returned, consistent with numpy.histogram." Check provided link... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram

Comment: `If bins is an int, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the given range (10, by default). ` May be this means crammed up. I didn't get the idea until you answered the question.

Comment: "range : (float, float), optional
The lower and upper range of the bins. If not provided, range is simply (a.min(), a.max())."